# create binary search function to find the position to insert the element

Tags: python, binary-search

Task: write a function binary_search that has O(log n) time complexity to find the position to insert the element such that:

```
binary_search(42, (-5, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10))
```

gives 6.

Please help me with this question. How do i approach it?

Comment: ... Who wrote `search()`?

Comment: 1. Discard `search()`. 2. Write `binary_search()`.

Comment: Avoid slicing such as `seq[:1]`. That can turn something that looks O(log n) into O(n)

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that might help:
This solution has a O(log(n)) runtime.  Similar to Binary Search
[Binary Search Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

```
def rec(nums, target, lower, upper):
    if (lower > upper):
        return lower
    mid = int((upper + lower) / 2)
    if (nums[mid] > target):
        return rec(nums,target,lower,mid-1);
    elif (nums[mid] < target):
        return rec(nums,target,mid+1,upper);
    else: 
        return mid
class Solution:
    def searchInsert(self, nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    return(rec(nums, target, 0,len(nums)-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant problem of binary search, it is the same as looking for the largest element in the sequence that is smaller than k(the element to be inserted) or the smallest element that is greater than k.

```
def binary_search_insert(target, seq):
    U = len(seq) - 1 
    L = 0 
    result = 0 
    if target <= seq[0]:
        result = 0 
    elif target >= seq[len(seq) - 1]: 
        result = len(seq)
    else:
        while L <= U:
            M = (L + U)/2
            if seq[M] <= target:
                L = M + 1 
            else:
                result = M 
                U = M -1
    return result

#test case
In [34]: seq
Out[34]: [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [35]: k = 2

In [36]: binary_search_insert(k, seq)
Out[36]: 2

In [37]: k = 2.5

In [38]: binary_search_insert(k, seq)
Out[38]: 2

In [39]: k = 3.5

In [40]: binary_search_insert(k, seq)
Out[40]: 3
```